# OpenSwing Framework

Tags: swing-app-framework

Is OpenSwing a good framework for developing professional desktop application?

Comment: This is a bad question. Please provide some context, different frameworks are good in different situations.

Comment: Well we have to finish a financial desktop application within five months.  We currently have another application in C# which is about 70% similar to the new project we have to deliver in this short period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently using the OpenSwing Framework. I can say only the best for the functionalities which are provided with the framework. It is a multitier concept with excelent data binding possibilities. My App uses a small Derby DB in background and I’m managing it with hibernate.

I’m sure, you will be able to advance very fast and provide a working prototype very quick. I would advice you to read the available doc first and to run the provided examples (http://oswing.sourceforge.net/).

However, it has another side which you should be aware of and you will probably notice by yourself if you run the examples. The GridFrame, GridFrameControler, DetailFrame, DetailFrameControler etc classes are not really generic. There are a lot of dependencies bult in and you will have to customize them again and again for every single implementation (can be seen in the demos).

I had another approach, I invested some time in building my own classes which are generic and using the unchanged OpenSwing classes in the background first.  Now I’m only setting the properties file where all details are pre-defined. The rest is generic and I don’t have to re-code again and again for every single frame. 
I hope this will help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I used the openswing in team for more than two years.

It's a pretty nice swing framework for the enterprise development used in the Internal.

It provide great component based by MVP pattern ,such as grid , document ...
If you try it , It's a good article for you about [Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

And try the demo in the source,It's quite good.

The [JAllInOne](http://jallinone.sourceforge.net/) is also a good demo for the framework also made by the mcarniel

and It's a personal project only developed by mcarniel. Thanks mcarniel's great work.